# How can I control 2 lights with 2 switches so that both lights can't be on at the same time?

Tags: electrical, lighting

My bathroom has 2 lights, each with its own switch.

I want to know if it is possible to make it so both lights cannot be on at the same time either by rewiring my current setup or replacing the switches with something else.

If it helps, I'm in Virginia, USA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a normal and a 3-way switche you can do this so you have a on/off (SW2) switch and a selector (SW1) switch.

[image]

Comment: @SpeedyPetey happy now?

Comment: Definitely. Considering the earlier (now removed) comments I was not the only one to think this.